Chinese bronze dagger inscriptions
I am adding photos of an Archistic bronze dagger mimicking a jade piece. On the obverse is an astronomical constellation and some calligraphic inscriptions; can anyone translate them, please?



Please upload the photo, or provide the link to where it is stored.

Yes I will do that thank you.

They attempted to put Chinese words there (永寶。。。哈。。。福。。。雲。。。佛相共看。。。家去平安), but I don't think this says anything coherent.

[水|永]寶片?哈秋?  [疆|福]? 局[雨|兩]?雲胭,  名?[佛|拂]相共看  為?家太平安

Thanks very much everyone.
